# Creating BluetoothSocket crashes with "Could not execute method of the activity"

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

```
long uuidHigh = new BigInteger("11bc4f7154ac9edb", 16).longValue();
long uuidLow =  new BigInteger("167bf05f9436bc0a", 16).longValue();
UUID uuid = new UUID(uuidHigh, uuidLow);

BluetoothSocket socket = null;
BluetoothAdapter blueAdapter = null;

blueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothDevice device = blueAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:07:AB:6A:96:7D");

try {
    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid); // CRASH!
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Result:
*E/AndroidRuntime(14079): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity*

Statements just before the "socket =" statement in the same method execute fine. Getting the device seems to work fine with getName() working on it.
The physical device it runs on has API 8.

The bluetooth dev guide cryptically says:

```
    // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

But createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() cannot take a String, it must take a UUID.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="intrax.demo.explore"
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BluetoothAct" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This very frequently happens when you mess up your Manifest or xml.  Could you post that, as well?

Comment: Added manifest. It's very simple.

Comment: Should I "close" something? I had a crash for another reason earlier, maybe the bluetooth is blocked somehow? But discovery() works fine.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the OS switching activities. It use to run "InputMethodManager" now and then, LogCat says.But code runs well between pressing a button and the crash. And logcat is in my activity when it crashes.